# nunit test working directory

Tags: c#, nunit

I have the following code (sample1.evol - file attached to my unit test project):

```
[Test]
public void LexicalTest1()
{
     var codePath = Path.GetFullPath(@"\EvolutionSamples\sample1.evol");
     //.....
}
```

I found that the working directory of test execution is not the assembly directory: (in my case codepath variable assigned to `d:\EvolutionSamples\sample1.evol`).

So, how can I change the execution working directory (without hardcode)? What will be the best practice to load any files attached to test case?

Comment: Remove the \ at the start or put a . before it?

Comment: Nunit has a [TestContext](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testContext&r=2.6.2) that includes the TestDirectory property and the WorkDirectory property

Comment: My question is, why are you reading files in your unit tests?

Answer (score 4):

You can use following to get the directory of assembly running the code something like

```
var AssemblyDirectory =  TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this for integration tests that need to access data files.

On any machine the test needs to run create a system environment variable named **TestDataDirectory** that points to the root of where your test data is.

Then have a static method that gets the file path for you..

```
public static class TestHelper
{
    const string EnvironmentVariable = "TestDataDirectory";
    static string testDataDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(EnvironmentVariable);

    public static string GetTestFile(string partialPath)
    {
        return Path.Combine(testDataDir, partialPath);
    }
}
```

...

```
[Test]
public void LexicalTest1()
{
    var codePath = TestHelper.GetTestFile(@"\EvolutionSamples\sample1.evol");
    //.....
}
```

Comment: Small tidbit on Environment Variables -  You often need to reboot a system before Environment Variables will be recognized by your code at runtime.  If you try this and it doesn't work, and haven't rebooted, try rebooting the system.

Answer (score 2):

I am using this code:

```
   var str = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
   if (str.StartsWith(@"file:\")){
       str = str.Substring(6);
   }
```

Getting  in str variable the assembly directory.

Answer (score 0):

We were having a problem where tests run using ReSharper and NCrunch would work, but the native VS Test Runner would not be able to find the files, when given just a relative file path for the test to use. I solved it by creating a function that you pass the relative test file path into, and it will give you the absolute file path.

```
private static string _basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(NameOfYourTestClassGoesHere).Assembly.Location);
private string GetAbsoluteTestFilePath(string relativePath) => Path.Combine(_basePath, relativePath);
```

You would then use the function like so:

```
var input = File.ReadAllLines(GetAbsoluteTestFilePath(@"TestData/YourTestDataFile.txt"));
```